# accessing files in a folder using python

Tags: python, directory

I have a python script that runs a program, which generates few .exe files and puts them in a folder. I want to access these exe files to do further testing, the problem is that this folder name is not static (it's dynamic? ), the name depends on the OS,compiler,binary type(64/32-bit), so I can't hard code the directory.

So What is the best to access folders like this? , I tried looking this up but I haven't got a clue as to how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the folder name as a parameter to your python script:

```
python myscript.py FolderName
```

In `myscript.py`:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

`sys.argv` gives you all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import platform
```

Use the [platform](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) module to generate the file path.

```
import os.path
```

Use the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module to play with paths in a nice way.